# Race around condition for particular case firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
-uniqueid1
      status:0
      userTokenId: uniqueid(which is null)
```

I am having a problem of race around condition where I don't know how firebase is implementing this case. The problem is as follows:

1. user checks status for whether the status is 0.
2. if status is 0 it adds its token to userTokenid field and status 1
3. if not then it does'nt add its tokenid.

Now the problem is when 2 or more user check status 0 and both enter the 2 point. This question might be pointless but I need to confirm. Do i have to worry about this case?

```
firebase.child('uniqueid1');

firebase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(datasnapshot.child('status').getValue().equals(0)){
            //update record for userTokenId and status 
        }
        else{
            //don't update
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both clients happen to update the same value around the same time with a `setValue()` or `updateChildren()` call, the last write wins.

If you don't want that, you should probably be [using a transaction](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions). From that documentation:

> When working with complex data that could be corrupted by concurrent modifications, such as incremental counters, we provide a [transaction operation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions). You give this operation two arguments: an update function and an optional completion callback. The update function takes the current state of the data as an argument and will return the new desired state you would like to write. For example, if we wanted to increment the number of upvotes on a specific blog post, we would write a transaction like the following:

```
Firebase upvotesRef = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/android/saving-data/fireblog/posts/-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY/upvotes");
upvotesRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData currentData) {
        if(currentData.getValue() == null) {
            currentData.setValue(1);
        } else {
            currentData.setValue((Long) currentData.getValue() + 1);
        }
        return Transaction.success(currentData); //we can also abort by calling Transaction.abort()
    }
    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot currentData) {
        //This method will be called once with the results of the transaction.
    }
});
```

Read the [documentation on `transaction()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions) for full details.

Comment: In that case, I highly recommend that you read the [Firebase programming guide for Android](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/), as that is where I copied this from. An hour spent there, will prevent many mistakes and questions down the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Firebase ref=firebase.child("order_details/"+orderId);
            ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                @Override
                public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData currentData) {
                    Log.d("status",currentData.getValue());
                    int status= (int) currentData.child("status").getValue();
                    if(status==0){
                        HashMap<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        map.put("TokenId",sharedPreferences.getString("tokenId",""));
                        map.put("status",1);
                        currentData.setValue(map);
                    }
                 ((MapLoadingActivity)getActivity()).setProgressVisibility(false);
                    return Transaction.success(currentData);
                }


                @Override
                public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }
            });
```

I know its late to ask the question,but doTransaction() is pretty weird sometimes it calls sometimes it simply returns null.Therefore i switched my approach to php by calling firebase using php wrapper class.Please do suggest ,if my approach is wrong.